# How can I use GSL with C++11 and the new STL?

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, gsl

I am setting up a new C++ project (in Xcode 4.6) and I would very much like to use the features of the new C++11 standard (lambda expressions, auto, etc.). I am trying to (statically) link the Gnu Scientific Library (GSL) into this project, using Darson's answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127824/xcode-4-3-3-cant-find-any-header-files) previous question. However, his answer suggests to change the compiler to LLVM GCC 4.2, which does not support the new C++11 features.

When I change to the default Apple LLVM compiler 4.2, build fails and I get a long list of errors that Xcode traces back to semantic issues (undeclared identifiers, unknown type names, etc.) in the headers of the new "libc++" STL.

So my question is: **Did anyone find a way to use GSL in the new C++11 standard?** It doesn't necessarily have to be in Xcode, I am comfortable using any (UNIX) IDE or build environment.

Comment: Darson's answer looks wrong to me; he talks about setting library search path to `/usr/include/lib`???  For that reason alone I would ignore it.

Comment: @trojanfoe I suppose he meant '/usr/local/lib', which in my case is '/opt/local/lib' (default macports library directory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to solve my own question, and I thought I'd share it with those who might be struggling with this as well.

Like I suspected, the problem occurred because my GSL install (from macports) was build against the "old" STL (libstdc++). Hence, my solution was to recompile GSL against the "new" STL (libc++). This is easily done by unpacking the sources and running

```
./configure CC=clang CFLAGS="-stdlib=libc++" LDFLAGS="-stdlib=libc++"
```

I also added `--disable-shared` to build the static library only, and `--prefix=...` to set the build path. Then all what's left is to run `make` and `make install`.